# How to append the specific path for image which is retrieve from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
{"image":[{
     "image_id":"4",
     "image_name":"http:\/\/www.dreamuretechnologies.com\/images\/ 1399356377_1155729519.jpg",
     "offer":"no way",
     "date_time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
     }],
  "success":1
}
```

Above result is coming from `json_encode()` so i just want make sure that my path must be valid in this case it appears like this

"http://www.dreamuretechnologies.com/images/ 1399356377_1155729519.jpg"

and i want like this:

"http://www.dreamuretechnologies.com/images/ 1399356377_1155729519.jpg"

Comment: actually i am creating web service for fetching images from database

Comment: Did u fetch the result in image SRC ?

Comment: Call the image_name from JSON and fetch in image SRC it will be works.

Comment: no actually my web-service shows the json_enocded output in web-browser

Comment: are you using jQueryAJAX ?

Comment: get the value of image_name from your Webservice and give in image SRC.

Comment: no i am simply fetching image name from database and the images which are stored at folder at server; i am appending the specified path of that folder before image name

Comment: actually i am appending like this (in while loop)  $url='http://www.dreamuretechnologies.com/images/';   $image["image_name"] =$url. $row["image_name"];

Comment: currently your "image_name" returns exact path like http://www.dreamuretechnologies.com/images/ 1399356377_1155729519.jpg so when u call the image_name you will get exact path and when when u call in to image src it will display the image.